# C# code for adaptive authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, open-source, captcha

Is there any C# code/classes/open-source/tools that is recommended for adaptive authentication?

Some functions of our app utilize a Captcha to avoid spamming or inappropriate behavior, which unfortunately also slows down our genuine users. I would like display the Captcha only if certain parameters look 'shady', such as unusual IP address locations, changing IP for the same account name, unusual browser configs (may hint at anonymization service) etc. etc.

I can obviously write code for this, but I assume it's a common enough problem that public resources would exist to help. We currently use the google Catchpa service, and obviously any solution that wraps that would be absolutely ideal.

Comment: Maybe you should give your question a different title to attract more answers. Are you actually looking for indicators how to find out that a bot might be (ab)using your website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to combine some of the non-obtrusive techniques and tools already available to handle the actual bot/spam detection. After you identify a possible risk, you can then prompt your visitor for a CAPTCHA validation before proceeding.

I do not know of an out-of-box CAPTCHA solution that will display itself based on certain criteria. This could be because what defines a 'bot' or 'spam' is largely subjective and is always changing. Furthermore, most modern bots have no problem identifying themselves as your garden-variety user agent.

That said, if you end up having to "roll your own", I would recommend showing the CAPTCHA if any of the following are true:

- **HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Crawler** returns true
- Akismet (http://akismetapi.codeplex.com/) returns a positive match for any input text
- A [HoneyPot](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/11/honeypot-captcha.aspx) returns a positive match
- Excessive hammering (count postbacks and/or page_loads in Session)
- Excessive sign-in attempts
- [NoBot](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/NoBot/NoBot.aspx) returns a positive match

Hope this helps